# G++ name mangling of global const variables

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, name-mangling

Can someone help me understanding the gcc name mangling conventions?

Consider the following test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int x = 42;
int y = 42;

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
        return 0;
}
```

When running `nm` I get the following (surprising?) result:

```
0000000000000000 T main
0000000000000000 D y
0000000000000000 r _ZL1x
```

This shows that the compiler only mangles global variables placed in the read only section. I would expect the compiler either to mangle ALL or NO global variables

Is this intended behaviour? For me it looks inconsistent.

Comment: Are you compiling as C or C++? Also notice that `x` is implicitly `static` (at least in C++), while `y` is not.

Comment: implicitly `static` really? That means that in two different compilation units the visible addresses of `x` would be different? Wow. Good to know. Fortunately C doesn't play games like this.

Comment: I am compiling as C++

Comment: When defining `y` as `static` it also gets mangled as `0000000000000000 d _ZL1y`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes. Without this rule, you'd get multiple-definition errors if you included a header with `const int x = 42;` in more than one .cpp file. It's defined C++11 [dcl.stc]§7

Comment: g++ does not mangle the names of global variables at all. `x` is static. Declare it as `extern const int x = 42` and g++ will not mange it either. This is *probably* for linking with C without having to declare global variables `extern "C"`. I don't know what merits such a design decision might have.

Comment: @aschepler, where do you have this from? I don't see any mention in the C standard that has the storage class modified because of `const`-qualification.

Comment: Linkage, not storage class. But yes, I was wrong. Huh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mangling is mostly used to distinguish linker symbols that would otherwise reasonably clash.

Since `x` is implicitly static, multiple translation units can legally have different variables all called `x`, so the symbol is mangled to avoid collisions.

Since `y` is *not* static, there can be only one global variable called `y` in the program, so there's no need to avoid collisions (they should either be flagged as ODR violations or de-duplicated by the linker).

The other use is for functions, to distinguish overloads with the same name but different argument lists. That clearly doesn't apply here.

Comment: Ok two things to sum up: Global const variables are implicitly static and only static variables in the file scope are mangled.

I don't see the necessity why static variables get mangled in C++. C can handle it without!? So for me that's only the side effect hiding the issue of global const variables being implicitly static.

To solve this issue I explicitly need to define them extern to make them globally visible.